# Trying to filter arrays with json_query

Tags: json, ansible, jmespath, json-query

I'm having issues using `json_query` to filter arrays that have a certain key value.

This is what shows as the API result when given the direct path to it.

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "accelerated_failback": false,
            "action": "sync",
            "allow_copy_fb": false,
            "bandwidth_reservation": null,
            "changelist": false,
            "check_integrity": true,
            "cloud_deep_copy": "deny",
            "conflicted": false,
            "database_mirrored": false,
            "delete_quotas": true,
            "description": "",
            "disable_file_split": false,
            "disable_fofb": false,
            "disable_quota_tmp_dir": false,
            "disable_stf": false,
            "enable_hash_tmpdir": false,
            "enabled": false,
            "encrypted": false,

        },
        {
            "accelerated_failback": false,
            "action": "sync",
            "allow_copy_fb": false,

etc ...........
```

The key value that I'm trying to filter is `enabled: true` which there are a few arrays that have that key value from the result.

How I am querying is with this example:

```
- name: Gain Eligible Policies {{ item.name }}
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: 'https://{{ item.endpoint_host }}:{{ item.endpoint_port | default(8080) }}/platform/7/sync/policies'
    user: '{{ item.endpoint_user }}'
    password: '{{ item.endpoint_password }}'
    validate_certs: '{{ item.verify_ssl | default(false) }}'
    force_basic_auth: true
    timeout: '{{ uri_timeout | default(30) }}'
  retries: '{{ uri_retries | default(3) }}'
  delay: '{{ uri_delay | default(10) }}'
  register: api_result
  loop: "{{ array_lookup_list }}"
  when: item.name not in ignore_clusters_list

- name: API output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ api_result.results.0.json.policies | json_query( policies )  }}"
  vars:
    policies: "[?enabled == 'true']"
```

And only shows this result:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": []
}
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

I've tried shortening the path to just the variable when showing the API output but it gives me an error of:

```
- name: API output
  debug:
    msg: "{{ api_result | json_query( *.policies[\"[?enabled == 'true']\"] )  }}"

result _______________________________

"fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected '.'. String: {{ api_result | json_query( *.policies[\"[?enabled == 'true']\"] )  }}"}"
```

Comment: This is not a [mre]. One cannot copy paste your api json result and test as the json is not complete and invalid. It is your responsibility to make it minimal and complete so that people trying to help can reproduce and eventually fix. That being said, unless you absolutely want to use json_query and fix your jmespath query, doing this with stock ansible filters is trivial => `{{ <your_var_with_above_example_list> | selectattr('enabled') }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the attribute *enabled* is boolean. Simply test it

```yaml
        policies: '[?enabled]'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    api_result:
      results:
        - json:
            policies:
              - {rec: 1, enabled: false, encrypted: false}
              - {rec: 2, enabled: true, encrypted: false}
              - {rec: 3, enabled: true, encrypted: false}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ api_result.results.0.json.policies|json_query(policies) }}"
      vars:
        policies: '[?enabled]'
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg:
  - enabled: true
    encrypted: false
    rec: 2
  - enabled: true
    encrypted: false
    rec: 3
```